# Factory bean 'customConversions' not found

Tags: spring, spring-data-mongodb

I'm trying to update my MongoDB libraries to the latest, and now have a couple of errors, which might or might not be related.  The first is in my applicationContext.xml, where I have the error "Factory bean 'customConversions' not found" next to this section:

```
<mongo:mapping-converter base-package="com.my.model">
    <mongo:custom-converters base-package="com.my.model.converters">
    </mongo:custom-converters>
</mongo:mapping-converter>
```

I can't see from the docs anything I might be missing.  What could be causing this, and what can I do to fix?

If I try to run the app, I now get:

```
org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingException: No mapping metadata found for java.util.Date
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:206) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.1.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
```

I'm using the following Maven Dependencies:

org.springframework.data: spring-data-mongodb: 1.1.1.RELEASE
org.springframework: core, spring-context, etc.:  3.2.1.RELEASE

Is this just a broken release, or am I doing something else wrong?  I had no issues using java.util.Date in my model classes before.

Comment: FYI, I've reverted to spring-data-mongodb 1.0.3.RELEASE and don't get these problems.  Still interested in knowing why it's happening though, for future updates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, this is some time later, but it might benefit people upgrading code and database from legacy MongoDB versions.

I think that Mongo changed the way some data was stored internally.  Or it could be that we exported data to JSON and then imported it again.  Either way, we were left with data that had both incorrect Date and incorrect ObjectId representations.  spring-data-mongo used to handle this but for whatever reason don't any longer.  The fix for us was to run the following type of script in the Mongo shell:

```
db.entity.find().forEach(
  function(o){
    delete o._id;
    if (typeof(o.createdTs) !== 'undefined' && typeof(o.createdTs.sec) !== 'undefined'){
        o.createdTs = ISODate(o.createdTs.sec);
    }
    if (typeof(o.updatedTs) !== 'undefined' && typeof(o.updatedTs.sec) !== 'undefined'){
        o.updatedTs = ISODate(o.updatedTs.sec);
    }

    try{
        db.entity2.insert( o );
    } catch (err){
        print("Following node conversion failed.  Error is: " + err);
        printjson(o);
    }

  }
);

db.entity2.renameCollection('entity', true);
```

Now this worked for us because we weren't using the Mongo Object ID at all - we've been using a different, uniquely indexed UUID field as an ID instead.  If you're referring to objectId at all anywhere else, you will need to create an objectId from the old string id and use that.

This has enabled us to upgrade to spring-data-1.1.0 and beyond, and has meant that we can now introduce spring-data-neo4j, which we were previously unable to do with this project due to this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Did you add it to the MongoTemplate? http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/1.0.0.M5/reference/html/#d0e2718

Comment: Yes, that config was in there from the earlier version - I hadn't changed it.  This issue cropped up when I upgraded my Maven dependencies - I've just gone back to the older versions for now until I have more time to play with it

Answer (score 0):

I had the same mapping exception (`org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingException`). One of the dates in the MongoDB records somehow had a date in the following format that could not be decoded by java.util.date:

```
"createdTime": {
    "dateTime": ISODate("2016-09-15T02:01:00.560Z"),
    "offset": {
        "_id": "Z",
        "totalSeconds": 0
    },
    "zone": {
        "_class": "java.time.ZoneOffset",
        "_id": "Z",
        "totalSeconds": 0
    }
}
```

Everything worked fine after I deleted that record.